# Why is this simple .js for loop stopping after one iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple little .js program that'll randomize an array of English words so that I can translate them into the Russian equivalent:

```
var vocab_array_1 = ["end/distance", "hour/o'clock", "voice/vote", "city", "water", "table", "child", "force/strength", "father", "woman"];

for (var i = 0; i < vocab_array_1.length + 3; i++){
    var random_index = vocab_array_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * vocab_array_1.length)];

/*random_array.push(random_index);*/
    var random_array = [];
    random_array[i] = random_index;
}
```

But it's simply returning the result of random_array[i] after a single iteration. You can see that I tried to use the .push() method to build a new array but realized that this method returns the array and thus stops the for loop.

Having removed that, I can't figure out why the for loop stops running after a once through.

NOTE: I'm sure javascript has methods for randomizing arrays; I'm trying to hand code a method for learning purposes.

EDIT:

I performed the recommended changes but couldn't get the random array to log to console. Here is the revised code:

```
var vocab_array_1 = ["end/distance", "hour/o'clock", "voice/vote", "city", "water", "table", "child", "force/strength", "father", "woman"];
var random_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vocab_array_1.length + 3; i++){
    var random_index = vocab_array_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * vocab_array_1.length)];
    random_array.push(random_index);
}

console.log(random_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Move this line

```
var random_array = [];
```

to top, because it gets initialised on every round.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
var vocab_array_1 = ["end/distance", "hour/o'clock", "voice/vote", "city", "water", "table", "child", "force/strength", "father", "woman"];

var random_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vocab_array_1.length + 3; i++){
    var random_index = vocab_array_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * vocab_array_1.length)];
    random_array.push(random_index);    
    //random_array[i] = random_index;
}
```

Initialize the array outside of your loop.

Comment: Thanks! I made those changes, but then tried to console.log(random_array); outside the for loop and got nothing. What's up with that?

Comment: Did you add the console.log after the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

As said in a previous answer move array initialization before the `for` loop:

```
 var random_array = [];
```

But also change

```
random_array[i] = random_index;
```

to

```
random_array.push(random_index);
// or
random_array[random_array.length] = random_index;
```

To get the shuffle result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can use `array.forEach()` instead of a `for`, if you want to execute code for every element of an array unless there's something you need to do that requires a for.

```js
vocab_array_1.forEach(
    function (element, index, array) {
        var random_index = vocab_array_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * vocab_array_1.length)];
   random_array.push(random_index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Answer is for people who came here searching something similar to  "loop stopped after one execution"**

If your loop stopped after one execution, chances are that you have nested loops, and are scoped wrongly: 
See example

```
functionA = async()=>{
  for (i = 0; i<count; i++) {
    ....
    ....
  }
}


functionB = async () =>{
  for (i=0;i<length; i++){
    result.push(await functionA());
  }
}
functionB();
```

Now in function B `i` has a global scope in both functions; 
If the case resembles yours, [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) it properly and it should work.

```
functionB = async () =>{
      for (var i=0;i<length; i++){    //    < ---------------- Note 'var'
        result.push(await functionA());
      }
    }
```